# Printing values for a determined number of times

Tags: python

I have a table containing:

```
table = [[2, 1],[5, 2],[6, 4],[4, 5],[1, 3],[3, 6]]
```

and what I'm trying to do is to print the elements in the table for a set number of times, provided by the user.

For example,

```
userinput = 1
```

then it should just print one element from the table, left to right which is just:

```
[2,1]
```

the same goes for user input such as:

```
userinput = 4
```

it should print:

```
[2, 1],[5, 2],[6, 4],[4, 5]
```

Here's what I attempted:

```
table = [[2, 1],[5, 2],[6, 4],[4, 5],[1, 3],[3, 6]]
n = len(arr)

user = int(input("Enter how many times to print: "))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(user):
        print(table[j])
```

but the code i wrote is printing out too many duplicate values.

For example, if

```
userinput = 1
```

the output i get is

```
[2,1]
[2,1]
[2,1]
[2,1]
  .
  .
```

which is wrong.

Comment: `print(table[:user])`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution. The `str` conversion and `[1:-1]` slicing are only necessary because of the specific format you specified.

```
table = [[2, 1],[5, 2],[6, 4],[4, 5],[1, 3],[3, 6]]

user = int(input("Enter how many times to print: "))

print(str(table[:int(user)])[1:-1])

# Enter how many times to print: 3
# [2, 1],[5, 2],[6, 4]
```

Comment: thanks slicing is one way to do it but would a for loop be able to accomplish the same? I'm working on for loops usage for different situations.

Answer (score 1):

This should do, no need for the `len(table)` or the `for` loop

```
table = [[2, 1],[5, 2],[6, 4],[4, 5],[1, 3],[3, 6]]

user = int(input("Enter how many times to print: "))

print(table[:user])
```

example:

```
user = 4
```

output:

```
[[2, 1], [5, 2], [6, 4], [4, 5]]
```

**EDIT:** from your comment, it seems you would like to use a for loop to achieve this. This can be done like this:

```
for i in range(user):
    print(table[i])
```

which returns:

```
[2, 1]
[5, 2]
[6, 4]
[4, 5]
```

and if you want it to print all on one line:

```
for i in range(user):
    print(table[i], end=' ')
    if i == user - 1:
        print()
```

returns:

```
[2, 1] [5, 2] [6, 4] [4, 5]
```

Comment: thanks. but is there any way to implement using for loop? I'm learning how to utilise for loops at this point.

Comment: See my edits, It's definitely possible, but clunkier